# Puppet Enterprise "puppet job run Unknown Puppet subcommand 'job'" although documentation indicates this is available

Tags: puppet-enterprise

I have Puppet Enterprise 2018.1 installed. According to this documentation https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2018.1/running_puppet_on_demand_from_the_cli.html I'm wanting to use "Running Puppet with the orchestrator", however the command described command does not exist?

`vagrant@pe:/$ sudo puppet job run
Error: Unknown Puppet subcommand 'job'`

Answer (score 1):

Although I was logged on to the master (PE) this does not have the client tools installed by default, so I needed to download (https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.3/installing_pe_client_tools.html) and install (my host is Ubuntu 16.04, so dpkg -i pe-client-tools_18.1.3-1xenial_amd64.deb).

The tools are not linked nor added to the path, and the documentation is misleading as to how to invoke, so not "puppet job" as in the documentation, instead (using show as an example)

```
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet-job show
```